# Using "if" as argument identifier

Tags: python, lxml

I want to generate the following xml file:

```
<foo if="bar"/>
```

I've tried this:

```
from lxml import etree
etree.Element("foo", if="bar")
```

But I got this error:

```
page = etree.Element("configuration", if="ok")
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

I'm using python 2.7.9 and lxml 3.4.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
etree.Element("foo", {"if": "bar"})
```

The attributes can be passed in as a dict:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("foo", {"if": "bar"})

print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

output

```
<foo if="bar"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
etree.Element("foo", **{"if": "bar"})
```

Answer (score -2):

'if' is a reserved word in Python, which means that you can't use it as an identifier.

Comment: So it's **impossible** to generate that xml using python?